# BeautifulSoup не может распарсить url с кириллическими символами

Tags: python, веб-программирование, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Не получатеся распарсить url с кириллическими символами

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request


html_doc = request.urlopen('http://кто.рф/').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
title = soup.title.string
print (title)
```

Постоянно вижу одну и ту же ошибку.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Энкодить-декодить не помогает.
Python3.4. BeautifulSoup 4.3.2

Comment: вам нужно преобразовать адрес в [punycode](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode). в интернете на самом деле нет кириллических доменов.

Comment: @etki спасибо за подсказку

Comment: @pnoob, пожалуйста, оформите это в виде ответа.

Comment: @soon, исправился, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Отлично. Также, пожалуйста, отметьте пост как правильный ответ (галочка слева).

Comment: @soon. Пишет, что смогу принять свой ответ через два дня. В понедельник чекну ее.

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` не имеет *никакого* отношения к вопросу, ошибку можно воспроизвести простым примером: `python3 -c "from urllib.request import urlopen; urlopen('http://кто.рф/')"` -- это *полный* пример. Старайтесь создавать *минимальные* примеры для вопроса. Полный traceback указывает на точное место, где ошибка происходит, поэтому его тоже полезно в вопрос добавлять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы самому не реализовывать обработку IDN, можно [`requests` библиотеку](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests # $ pip install requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

r = requests.get('http://кто.рф')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, from_encoding=r.encoding)
```

Comment: Отличное решение и меньше текста, только работает на секунду дольше чем моя пачка строчек, если вдруг кому будет принципиально время.

Comment: @pnoob: секунда—это слишком большой промежуток. Код скорее всего ограничен задержкой сети, поэтому никакая библиотека на клиенте не сделает единственный запрос быстрее.  Напротив, `requests` использует connection pool автоматически, поэтому *несколько* запросов должны быстрее проходить.

Answer (score 2):

Решил следующим способом

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request

url = 'http://кто.рф/'
parts = list(urlsplit(url))
parts[1] = parts[1].encode('idna').decode('ascii')
url = urlunsplit(parts)
html_doc = request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
title = soup.title.string
print (title)
```